# Actions on Google + Interactive Canvas Game + Device Orientation

Tags: actions-on-google, phaser-framework, google-assistant

I am creating a game for google assistant using actions builder and interactive canvas (Phaser 3 Framework). I have two questions:

1. How to handle device orientation as most smart displays are in landscape orientation while smartphones are in portrait orientation.
2. I can create two games, one in portrait mode and another in landscape mode. Is there any way by which I can do conditional loading of interactive canvas game url? for eg: portrait mode game for smartphones and landscape mode game for smart displays?

Please note that I already tried adding multi resolution support in the game but the graphics and design is in such a way that it doesn't look good.

Thanks-in-advance

Answer (score 1):

There's no direct way to do this. One potential workaround you could use is checking if the device supports the [`actions_capability_web_browser`](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/df-asdk/surface-capabilities?hl=en#conversation_branching) capability, which is only available on phones and not smart displays.